# How to speedup generating urls?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, amazon-web-services

I have the following method that generates `URLs` for me:

```
async def get_url_for_ids(self, ids: List[int]) -> List[str]:
    urls = []
    async with self.session.create_client('s3', region_name=self.region_name) as s3:
        for id in ids:
            url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                  Params={'Bucket': self.bucket_with_videos,  'Key': '{}.mp4'.format(id)})
            urls.append(url)
    return urls
```

This method is the slowest part in my app. Even query to the DB works much faster. `get_url_for_ids` works around `15 sec` if `ids` contains for example `30,000` elements.

How to speed up it?

Comment: 2000 per second is pretty fast! Why are you creating so many pre-signed URLs? Applications normally generate pre-signed URLs only when a user requests access to an object in Amazon S3. That way, the expiration time can be based on the request time. So why are you pre-generating 30,000+ URLs?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are doing with your list of URLS one option could be to use a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator). This would mean the the whole list of URLs wouldn't need to be computed before you can start using them.

```
async def get_url_for_ids(self, ids: List[int]) -> List[str]:
    async with self.session.create_client('s3', region_name=self.region_name) as s3:
        for id in ids:
            url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',
                  Params={'Bucket': self.bucket_with_videos,  'Key': '{}.mp4'.format(id)})
            yield url
```

To use this generator it must be in an async function, and the for loop is prefixed with `async`:

```
async def main():
    async for item in get_url_for_ids():
        #do something
```

---

If you *need* the list pre-computed and available in memory, then I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what size self.bucket_with_videos is but I suspect it is large and the API is doing a linear, or possibly accidentally quadratic[1](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/), search over it.

Comment: Generating signed URLs doesn't contact the service -- they're generated locally, but do require relatively CPU intensive HMAC-SHA operations. 2K/sec is actually pretty respectable.